# How to extract specific string from files that matches Pattern in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have a requirement: To scan in a directory for all the application logs ($dir) present and pick the latest one ($fileList) to check that if the latest log file contains "error" (pattern) in the log file ($fileList). Then extract all the required information from them and store them in variable so as to pass to json as parameter to Azure Log Analytics workspace.

I have written like :

```
$dir = 'C:\ProgramData\AecorsoftDataIntegrator\logs\'
$fileList = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '2022*.log' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).fullname
$search= (Get-Content $fileList | Select-String -Pattern 'error')
```

The log looks like :
[log file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gej1H.jpg)

I would like to extract the : error time : (highlighted in yellow in the image link) ; job name : OPT_VIM1_HEAD (highlighted in yellow in the image link) and if possible the whole error message (marked in red barces) and store them in some variables so that I can process them and display them in console

Please help me with the script. Newbie to powershell

Comment: If you want to include the 14 lines immediately following a match add `-Context 0,14` to the `Select-String` call. You can also skip `Get-Content` entirely: `$search = Select-String -LiteralPath $fileList -Pattern error -Context 0,14`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen how to get Name:OPT_VIM_1HEAD (this job name has to be dynamic)  and store them in variable and timestamp : 2022-09-02 02:13:05 

The total output for your code :

C:\ProgramData\AecorsoftDataIntegrator\logs\2022-09-02.log:2270:2022-09-01 23:13:05Z | error | 2022-09-02 02:13:05 - [Task] Id:120 Name:OPT_VIM_1HEAD Exception with index:18 | 18.9251137 | Exception:
  C:\ProgramData\AecorsoftDataIntegrator\logs\2022-09-02.log:2271:LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode